# Setting up Bluetooth (BLE) communication between Arduino UNO and Laptop running Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluno

I have a bluno (arduino uno with a built-in BLE[TI CC2540]) and laptop (ubuntu) with a built-in Bluetooth module.

I want to make a Bleutooth BLE communication program between arduino and linux.

I want to send data from linux to arduino.

Any help would be awesome!

(reference) below  operation confirm

> $sudo hciconfig

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB

```
BD Address: 6C:71:D9:B1:A5:1A  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
RX bytes:1786 acl:16 sco:0 events:99 errors:0
TX bytes:1407 acl:12 sco:0 commands:65 errors:0
```

> $ hciconfig hci0 up
>
> $ sudo hcitool lescan

LE Scan ...

D0:39:72:C4:CA:72 (unknown)

D0:39:72:C4:CA:72 Bluno

Comment: Your question's title mentions Raspberry Pi, but I cannot seem to see any mention of it in the body; is there something missing in the description?

Comment: sorry, i think that Raspberry pi is equal ubuntu. so i told you ubuntu. thank~!

Answer (score 0):

And where exactly is your problem respectively at which stage is your development currently?

In general:
You have somehow to talk with the bluetooth module on your linux system (Raspberry?). For this you need e.g. API-calls to give and read command from you bluetooth module. If there are no read-to-use APIs then you need to write it yourself, reading the manual of the module and communicating with it using SPI, I2C,...

After a successful hardware-communication with your bluetooth module on the linux system, you have to communicate with the BLE module. For this developing a protocol with cyclic redundancy checks,... would be a good idea, insted of sending plain "chars".

Comment: Upvote if it helps solve the issue you were having, so it can be seen that the problem has been solved ;)